# C++ strcmp array

Tags: c++, c, arrays, strcmp

I am using strcmp as shown below.

I am debugging the values and which are coming same but still not getting that condition true.

```
const char opcode_read[2] = {'0', '1'};

rc = recvfrom(s, blk_receive_full, sizeof (blk_receive_full), 0,(struct sockaddr FAR *)&sin, &fromlength);

if(rc == -1){
    printf("failed: recvfrom, \n No data received \n failed code: %d\n",WSAGetLastError());
    cleanup();
    exit(1);
}

memcpy(blk_receive_opcode, &blk_receive_full, 2);
if (strcmp(blk_receive_opcode, opcode_data) == 0) {
}
```

Comment: Do you intend for the ASCII characters 0 and 1, or the binary values 0 and 1 to be matched here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can tell, you aren't comparing two strings as they aren't null-terminated. You may want to use `memcmp()` instead:

```
if (memcmp(blk_receive_opcode, opcode_data, 2) == 0) {
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**opcode_read** is not a string.   There is no NUL termination.
Change its size to 3, so you pick up a NUL in the third position.

```
const char opcode_read[3] = {'0', '1'};
```

An alternative would be to use **memcmp** instead of **strcmp** so you don't have to worry about the pesky NUL terminator.

The **recvfrom** call is a bit scary too.   If I recall my TCPIP correctly.   There is no guarantee that the function will return 2 bytes in one call.   It may return one byte, in the first call, and the second byte in the second call.

Comment: blk_receive_opcode's not null-terminated either, and since the lengths are fixed he might as well use `memcmp`

Comment: A better alternative is to write `const char opcode_read[] = "01";` but that may just be me.

Comment: Probably depends whether or not data being trasmitted is intended to be interpreted as a single string (e.g. `"hello"`) or an "array of chars" (e.g. `{ 'T', 'F', 'T' }` as an array of three "boolean" values). The code is identical in either case (as long as you remember the latter example does not add the null terminator)

Comment: @bdonlan ya, i should have caught the other one wasn't NUL terminate either.

@chris  that is a style preference.  I was going with the style that the questioner had.

@GRB i agree it depends on the interpretation of the data.  the questioner seemed interested in strings, so i shaped my answer that way.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to try `memcmp` instead.  `strcmp` is for null terminated strings.